# GDB doesn't work: Cannot insert breakpoint 1. Cannot access memory at address [...]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, g++, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to setup my vscode to debug C++ programs using gdb from WSL. But I faced problem with gdb on my WSL 1 (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS). Whenever I try set a breakpoint and run a program, I get the following error:

```
Starting program: /mnt/d/Informatics/vscode/test/a.out
warning: opening /proc/PID/mem file for lwp 7674.7674 failed: No such file or directory (2)
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x10e0
```

The contents of the program don't matter, always getting the error. Code is compiled using the following line:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic-errors -O2 -std=c++23 -ggdb3 -fdiagnostics-color=always /mnt/d/Informatics/vscode/test/*.cpp
```

gdb version: `GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.0.90-0ubuntu1) 12.0.90`
g++ version: `12.0.1` (also tried with `11.2.0` - no difference)

On windows with g++ and gdb from MinGW the problem doesn't exist, so this should mean I'm not using the gdb debugger wrong.

---

Edit: tried compiling gdb 11.2 from source as suggested in comments, but this did not fix the problem. Only difference is that it's not showing `/proc/PID/mem` warning now.

```
Starting program: /mnt/d/Informatics/vscode/test/a.out
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x10e0
```

---

Edit 2: Compiled gdb 10.2 from source and it works, the problem does not appear. I don't know why it doesn't work with any version above 10.2. Is it gdb bug or WSL bug?

Comment: I know you mentioned that 11.2.0 didn't work, but did you try compiling 11.2 from source? Per this vcode cpptools [ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9135) it seems like that would do the trick. I just tried it myself following [these instructions](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/gdb.html) and it worked great. I'm able to set breakpoints again.

Comment: I tried to **compile with g++ 11.2.0**, not to debug with gdb 11.2.
Tried that now, same problem except it's not showing `opening /proc/PID/mem file for ... failed ...`.

Comment: Have you tried `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` ?

Comment: @Philippe No, I upgraded to `Ubuntu 22.04` and I don't have 20.04

Comment: Maybe it's worth trying `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`, if possible. 22.04 might be too new.

Comment: Is the executable compiled with the Ubuntu or Windows gcc?

Comment: @Philippe I don't have `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` on WSL anymore

Comment: @ssbssa With Ubuntu gcc of course.

Comment: In WSL, you can create another distribution for `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`.

Comment: @Philippe but after the upgrade to 22.04 wsl -l in cmd still says Ubuntu-20.04, while lsb_release -a in wsl says Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I'm not sure if this is a problem.

Comment: @Philippe Ignore the previous comment, I managed to install `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`. But apt version of gdb is 9.2 and of course it works with it (it will also work from Ubuntu 22.04 with gdb 9.2 I suspect). Should I compile gdb 11.2 from source and install it in Ubuntu 20.04 and check if it works?

Comment: Indeed, that's a good option.

Comment: @Philippe, tried it, not working, same issue.

Comment: @Lassie Have you tried following this guide? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl#_debug-helloworldcpp

Comment: @MohamedFarid The problem is not with VS code settings. Old versions of gdb work with VS code and new versions of gdb don't work even when I'm using them outside of VS code (from terminal for example).

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Arch Linux on a Virtual Machine running in Chrome OS. I think this is a Virtual Machine related problem. (Because I think WSL is also a virtual machine). At a very high level(without really knowing any of the details), I have a hunch that gdb packages compiled for regular OS don't work on top of a virtual-machine, but when we rebuild them, that works.

Comment: OK I just tried it on Debian and it worked, so somehow it's OS specific, or specific to the version of GDB. Debian is running GDB 10.1, Arch Linux is running GDB 12.1.

Now I think the problem involves version number as well.

Comment: Update: didn't work: locally built and installed gdb using the Arch package scripts, same error.

Comment: Can confirm on Arch Linux over ChromeOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in newer versions: everything seems to work fine in gdb 13.1 on Ubuntu 23.04 (WSL).