# Break main issue in GDB

Tags: linux, gdb

When I debug `file.out` with GDB and type `start` in GDB, the program cannot insert a breakpoint in main.

There are also some warnings:

```
warning: opening /proc/PID/mem file for lwp 1625.1625 failed: No such file or directory (2)
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x8001129
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Looks related https://stackoverflow.com/q/71961944/72178

Comment: How did you set the breakpoint?

Comment: did you check whether /proc/1625/mem exists?

Comment: Are you using WSL 1? https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8356

Answer (score -3):

Did you use `-g` flag when compiling the program?

`-g` flag, on most compilers, is used to provide debugging info (like function address) for debuggers.